# The tin foil hat brigade ruined a question

Tags: discussion

[Is this "security update" from security-update@amazon.com an advanced phishing scam or a real security measure from Amazon?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/127139/is-this-security-update-from-security-updateamazon-com-an-advanced-phishing-s)

I've recent received this email myself. My conclusion is that the email is legitimate. I've not based this on the content or headers of the email, which can be faked by advanced scammers. I've based this on the fact that my Amazon password has become invalid, at the same time. A scammer wouldn't usually be able to do that. A couple of the answers also mention this.

The problem with the question is the voting on answers. The "it's fake" answers get upvoted and the "it's legit" answers get downvoted. I can see why - there's a large "tin foil hat" brigade on this site, who have just enough knowledge to be dangerous. I've often thought the voting on questions and answers is completely out of whack. But this is the first time that it's ended up promoting wrong answers.

I realise I could ask OP to accept one of the "it's legit" answers. However, he has answered his own question, and spread more confusion, so I don't think asking him to do that will help.

Not quite sure what to do here, can mods accept an answer?

Comment: I would recommend always assuming malicious over legitimate. Worst case scenario you'd have wasted some time if you were wrong.. However the consequences of thinking the opposite can be much worse should you be wrong.

Comment: @AndréBorie While I recommend that everyone assume malicious over legitimate it appears the asker is assuming it is possibly malicious and asking if it is legitimate. So from here respondents should not be echoing what the OP has already done but instead help assess and address the issue. While we know the outcome of this particular question this particular issue is still a tricky one. Since if it is legitimate it could indicate they OP has in fact had his password compromised. And writing it off as fake based off tin foil hattery over facts could deter the OP from looking into it further.

Answer (score 4):

Looks from the OP that their situation is not the same as yours - their password **was not** changed, which lends credence to them having suffered a spoof.

Sure, it looks like the valid one you had, but that should be the case for a good attack.

Mods are not able to accept answers on behalf of an OP, but as we're not in a position to be able to confirm or deny whether they were attacked, we wouldn't want to do this anyway.

I agree with you that the answers are best guess - but that is true for both the True and False answers on this. To be honest, the problem is the question, not the Tin Foil Hat Brigade.

Comment: I am extremely sceptical of OP's claim their password was not changed. I have a feeling they reset it when they first got the email, then "forgot" about it.

Comment: Completely separately, are you on the White Hat Rally this year?

Comment: That is absolutely possible - unfortunately we can't know. Wonder whether the question itself should just be closed.

Comment: Re WHR - sadly no. I tried, but with work in cost-cutting phase I couldn't get a sponsored team, and with staff reductions I couldn't get time away :-(

Comment: Next year! Surely!